# How to use async/await in typescript

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, async-await, angular, ecmascript-2016

I want to call a `http.get` method off my `ThemeService` and make it as "synchronous" as possible so that it continuous after it gets `Theme` from the call. I searched on how to do this and stumbled across `async` and `await`. I tried to implement this but it didn't quite work. I put some `console.log()` in the code so i can see what is and what isn't executed. The "IN ASYNC FUNCTION" and "AFTER ASYNC" are executed but not the ones after/in my call on `ThemeService`.

Because i am new to the `async/await` functions in typescript i don't know if what I have written is badly or if what i'm trying to do is possible or not.

```
ngOnInit():void{
    let id = +this.routeParams.get('themeId');
    async function getTheme(){
        console.log("IN ASYNC FUNCTION");
        var val =  await this.themeService.getTheme(id).subscribe((theme:Theme)=> {
            this.theme = theme;
            console.log("IN AWAIT FUNCTION")
        });
        console.log("AFTER AWAIT");
        return val;
    }

    getTheme();
    console.log("AFTER ASYNC");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have it like this (note usage of 'take(1).toPromise()'):

```
ngOnInit():void
{
    let id = +this.routeParams.get('themeId');
    async function getTheme()
    {
        console.log("IN ASYNC FUNCTION");
        var val =  await this.themeService.getTheme(id).take(1).toPromise();
        console.log("AFTER AWAIT");
        return val;
    }

    this.theme = await getTheme();
    console.log("AFTER ASYNC");
}
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit
{
    async ngOnInit() 
    {
        let id = +this.routeParams.get('themeId');
        this.theme = await this.themeService.getTheme(id).take(1).toPromise();
        console.log("AFTER ASYNC");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it both ways but nothing worked out, `this.theme` didn't get a value. The "AFTER ASYNC" isn't logged in the console. If i put a `console.log("int method")` within the `getTheme()` methode, It doesn't log it in the console either

Comment: try first replacing your themeService.getTheme() async method with some dummy method that just logs when its get called and returns something like Promise.resolve(), to see that its not the issue with  themeService.

Comment: I changed the content of `getTheme` to just log something in console and return Promise.resolve() instead of Observable<Theme> and that works. But the getTheme methode works if i use it normally instead of in async/await.

Comment: Ok. Can you replace content of getTheme to return with something like: rx.Observable.just(123), and see if it will work.

Comment: He still shows the logs after i return an Observable but once i try to get the  value of the observable with the ".take(1).toPromise()" it doesn't log the "AFTER SYNC" message

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem but i'm targeting ES6, does that support async calls?

Comment: its not a problem. So far typescript support async/await only if compiled to es6.